# Per chart indicators created using pine-script in trading view (like the drawings)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I created a custom indicator in trading view using pine-script. The inputs to the indicator depend on the chart that is open. Also I do not want the indicator visible in all charts.

Basically what I want is to indicator behave like the drawing tools. If I draw some line and plots using the left side drawing menu, those are only applied to the current chart and not others.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

With pinescript (V5) there is no link beetween the execution and the chart/tab open by the user.

So you can't act like the drawing tools.

A workaround is to retrieve the pair name from the chart choosen by the user.

You can use **syminfo.tickerid** to know the pair choosen by your user and activate/deactivate your indicator.

This way, your indicator will only work on pairs you decide.